# iTMSTransporter : How to upload content in In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itmstransporter

I'm actually using ITMSTransporter, and try to computerize management of in app purchases.

I read all documentation about ITMSTransporter : Lookup Mode, Verify Mode, Upload Mode.
But I have still a problem with in app purchase.

**I have an in app purchase and I need to upload content, like .json, .jpg etc ...
I can do that with Application Loader**(for example) **but i want to use Transporter. Well, how can I upload .pkg file with .itmps file ?**

I think, I need to modify metadata.xml in the .itmps file but I'm not sure.
Could you plz give me more information about uploading content in my in-App purchases

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As of Xcode 9.1 Beta you can upload In-App Purchase content from Xcode’s Organizer window, and create/update metadata through iTunes Connect as before.

If you would like to use ITMSTransporter, you first download the metadata .itmps file associated with your app, then edit it as necessary (including dragging any .pkg files into the .itmps file, which is really directory you can view by ctrl-clicking and selecting "show contents").

Once edited you use the command line to verify and upload it. An example workflow for updating an existing in-app purchase's content would be thus:

**Step 1 : Get the existing metadata for the in app purchase:**

```
iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u "$ITC_USERNAME" -p "$ITC_PASSWORD" -destination "$DOWNLOAD_PATH" -vendor_id "$ITC_PRODUCT_PARENT_ID" -subitemids "$ITC_PRODUCT_ID" -subitemtype InAppPurchase
```

You can omit the -subitemids and -subitemtype options if you wish to simply download the metadata for the entire app and all of its IAPs.

This produces an .itsmp locally, inside of which you will find "metadata.xml".

You can edit this metadata as required, and even add/remove entire sections. Refer to the [ITMSTransporter guide](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/) to see how to edit the XML in detail.

**Step 2 : Update your local copy of the metadata**

- Drag the new IAP content, which you should have archived into a .pkg file using XCode, into the .itmsp directory the previous step generated.
- Update the size and md5 checksum in the region of the xml file which carries that information.  The md5 checksum for your .pkg is obtainable by opening terminal and typing "md5" then dragging and dropping the .pkg into terminal and pressing enter.

**Step 3 : Verify the .itmsp package**

```
iTMSTransporter -m verify -u "$ITC_USERNAME" -p "$ITC_PASSWORD" -f "$ITMSP_PATH"
```

**Step 4 : Upload (assuming verification was successful)**

```
iTMSTransporter -m upload -u "$ITC_USERNAME" -p "$ITC_PASSWORD" -f "$ITMSP_PATH"
```

This workflow was taken/adapted from the following website, which is extremely helpful and carries other relevant information you may want:
http://www.cyrilchandelier.com/having-fun-with-itmstransporter